# Hide JDK path showing in Run window in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any way I can remove the whole path and jar files from showing every time I run a program?

[image]

Would just like to see the exact responses ('Hello, World!', in this case) from the program.

Thanks.